# VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel" not working for .Net 4.6.2. Need alternatives

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, datagrid

I have a Datagrid with more than 2000 rows and the initial loading was very very slow but once everything was loaded, the srolling down was pretty fast. I added the following properties to my style and the performance improved by 5 times.

```
<Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True"/>
<Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Recycling"/>
<Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="True"/>
<Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
```

But after this, my scrolling became slower. I know that this is happening because now I'm loading as I scroll down.

I have read some posts about pixel loading and I have to set `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll = false` and I don't want to do that because turning that to false is slowing my application down.

I have also read that in .Net 4.5 and higher versions, there is a hack to set the pixel scrolling by doing `VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"`. I'm using .Net 4.6.2 and I don't see this improving my scroll performance. Is there something that can be done to not compromise either on application performance or the scroll performance?

Comment: Is your `DataGrid` being populated from a collection in memory, or is it constantly querying the database? What type of data are you displaying? Are there events tied to the `DataGrid` scroll or selection change events? 2000 rows is nothing and shouldn't cause the delay you are describing in normal cases.